# How can I get sectioned tables in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, json, phpmyadmin

I'm using phpMyAdmin to create tables for my project database. Currently my tables are in this order `table->{contents}` but I want them to be like this `table->section_name1{contents},section2_name{contents}`. An example of what I want in JSON format is in this [link](http://monaasoft.com/indianfm/api/test.json).

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you're asking. If you just want the content in the tables to be groupable by section_name, like in the JSON example, then you just need to make section_name a column in your table and populate it appropriately for each section.

If it's not that then can you please explain in more detail what you are trying to do?

EDIT: Like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Title     | Name        | Image                                       |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Section 1 | Donut       | https://thecustomizewindows.com/wp-....     |            
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Section 1 | Eclairs     | https://thecustomizewindows.com/wp-....     | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Section 1 | Froyo       | https://thecustomizewindows.com/wp-....     | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Section 2 | Donut       | https://thecustomizewindows.com/wp-....     | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Section 2 | Eclairs     | https://thecustomizewindows.com/wp-....     | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Section 2 | Froyo       | https://thecustomizewindows.com/wp-....     | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Section 3 | Donut       | https://thecustomizewindows.com/wp-....     | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Section 3 | Eclairs     | https://thecustomizewindows.com/wp-....     | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: you mean like create a column and only give it a value where the section starts and leave it empty in the rest?

Comment: I dont think that will work.Please look at the raw data for the first link I sent

Comment: I did look at the JSON, where you have each set of items with a name under the section that has a title.

You wouldn't only give it a value where the section starts, you would give it a value for all of the items that fit within that section. It won't let me put a table here in the comments so I'll try adding to the original answer.

Comment: I cant really get what you mean.Also is the link supposed to be an image or something?Im new to phyMyAdmin so some guideline would be highly appreciated